# There is an error when using dropezone and trying to upload a file into my widget

Tags: node.js, express, zoho

im trying to upload files from my local pc into a conversation in whatssap using dropezone, however, when trying to upload, there is an error with the post.

i am working on a project using zoho platform, infobip, express and dropezone: i am sending a screenshot to show the code i have at the moment.

```
`const uploadFolder = "uploads/";

// Verificar si la carpeta 'uploads' existe, si no, crearla
const fs = require("fs");
if (!fs.existsSync(uploadFolder)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(uploadFolder);
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: uploadFolder, // Carpeta donde se guardarán los archivos subidos
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname); // Utiliza el nombre original del archivo
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post("/upload", upload.single("fileToUpload"), (req, res) => {
  // El archivo subido estará disponible en req.file
  if (req.file) {
    console.log("Archivo subido:", req.file);
    // Aquí puedes realizar acciones adicionales con el archivo, como guardarlo en la base de datos, procesarlo, etc.
    res.send("Archivo subido exitosamente.");
  } else {
    res.status(400).send("No se encontró ningún archivo para subir.");
  }
});

// Configura el directorio estático para servir los archivos subidos
app.use(express.static(uploadFolder));

// Iniciar el servidor
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor iniciado en el puerto ${port}`);
});
```

but when trying to upload a file, it doesn't upload into dropezone square and is showing this error that i am sending you in a photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiyoB.png)

What can be the error?`

Comment: Be mindful of grammar.